# React Native Ternary Operator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I am trying to use a ternary operator to truncate a user name and add `...` if over a certain char length. I've tried a few ways but keep coming back to this, below is the original code and what I have now.

```
<Text style={styles.userText}>{name}</Text>
```

```
<Text style={styles.userText}>
      {name.length > 27 ? name.substr(0, 27)`...` : name} -
    </Text>
```

The error I receive in the simulator is "name.substr(0, 27) is not a function" which I am aware of but unsure of why it returns that.

I appreciate any feedback and help.

Comment: I am not sure why it throws such error if name is a string. But, if name is actually a string, use this. `\`${name.substr(0, 27)}...\`` using string literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ternary operator should work with the string literals. This will work.

```
<Text style={styles.caregiverText}>
  {name.length > 27 ? `${name.substr(0, 27)}...` : name} -
</Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to @OmkarKulkarni for the comment the solution is below:

```
<Text style={styles.caregiverText}>
      {name.length > 27 ? `${name.substr(0, 27)}...` : name} -
    </Text>
```